MUI X Data Grid- filter reset issue
I'm using @mui/x-data-grid(6.14.0) to show list of users. My first column has action button on click of action button I'm opening tooltip (mui component) which works as expected on normal use. But if I filter the data grid using GridToolbarFilterButton and click on action button, my data grid is resetting with all the users in list.
This is my code
<DataGrid
            rows={data ? data : []}
            getRowId={(row: any) => row.patientId}
            columns={columns}
            onRowClick={rowSelect}
            slots={{
              toolbar: CustomToolbar,
            }}
            initialState={{
              pagination: {
                paginationModel: { pageSize: 10, page: 0 },
              },
            }}
            pageSizeOptions={[10, 25, 50]}
            rowSpacingType='margin'
            getRowClassName={(params: any) => (params.indexRelativeToCurrentPage % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd')}
            style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
          />

On action button I'm calling this function
const handleTooltipOpen=(e:any, id:number)=>{
e.stopPropagation();
setOpen(id);
dispatch(getConversationGroupDetails(id))
  .unwrap()
  .then((response:any) =>{
    if(response?.status === 200){
      setGroupDetails(response.data);
    }
  });

};

It is unclear as you have not provided Actions button functionality. The problem is unclear. create a sandbox so the problem is reproducible.

I'm calling this function on my action button -
const handleTooltipOpen=(e:any, id:number)=>{
e.stopPropagation();
setOpen(id);
dispatch(getConversationGroupDetails(id))
.unwrap()
.then((response:any) =>{
if(response?.status === 200){
setGroupDetails(response.data);
}
});
};

My observation is, it is due to the state change, happening on action button call.

The issue was due to the styled grid. It was declared inside the main component. After declaring styled grid out of the main component it is working.
